# Definition of Event date in _bounce data view in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, data-views, bounce-management

This is with reference to standard system data extension in marketing cloud named _bounce.

As per standard documentation definition of EventDate is "The date the bounce took place."

Let's say, email was sent to day 1, and bounce was reported by server on day 3, marketing cloud updated the same on day 4 in _bounce data view. What would be EventDate in this case ? (day1, day3 or day4?)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'Marketing Cloud updated the same on day 4'? I believe that once the server reports it to SFMC, it is added to the DV within minutes

Comment: @Gortonington : Ideally day3 & day4 should be same but I just wanted to know that which time EventDate is. Purpose of this question was to create an automation which will run on daily basis and mark junk all bounce email ids in sales cloud. I might have missed few email ids if EventDate was not day3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EventDate is the date when the Salesforce Mailserver has received and processed the information that the mail has bounced which has been sent from Recipients Mail Server. Usually these information come with a timestamp inside the bounce message of the recipient mail server.

To be honest: It is day 3 just like Gortonington said in his comment. There is barely no timegap when the data is written into the dataview _bounce. It is not something where salesforce will process every information over night -> it is close to instant.